# Web scrapping to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project and my code is working. I just don't know how to avoid the newline spaces in the cvs file. The Udemy instructors is using a dictionary to store all the data with no newline issue. Is that the only way to avoid this?

````
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from csv import writer

   response = requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/")
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
   quotes = soup.find_all(class_="quote")

   with open("web_scraping.csv", "w") as f:
       csv_writer = writer(f)
       csv_writer.writerow(["Title", "Author", "Link"])

       for quote in quotes:
           texts = quote.find(class_="text").get_text()
           author = quote.find(class_="author").get_text()
           link = quote.find("a")["href"]
           csv_writer.writerow([texts, author, link])

    ```
    OUTPUT
    ```
    Title,Author,Link

    “The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed 
    without changing our thinking.”,Albert Einstein,/author/Albert-Einstein

    "“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our 
    abilities.”",J.K. Rowling,/author/J-K-Rowling

    “There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The 
    other is as though everything is a miracle.”,Albert Einstein,/author/Albert-Einstein

    "“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be 
    intolerably stupid.”",Jane Austen,/author/Jane-Austen

    "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous 
    than absolutely boring.”",Marilyn Monroe,/author/Marilyn-Monroe

    “Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”,Albert 
    Einstein,/author/Albert-Einstein

    “It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”,André 
    Gide,/author/Andre-Gide

    "“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”",Thomas A. 
    Edison,/author/Thomas-A-Edison

    “A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot 
     water.”,Eleanor Roosevelt,/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt

    "“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”",Steve Martin,/author/Steve-Martin
````

Comment: it might be the editor you're viewing in. ran your code as is and got a csv file without any extra new lines

Comment: I am using PyCharm and it is still not working. I used the filter method to get rid of it.

Comment: `code` with open("web_scraping.csv") as f:
    reader = reader(f)
    list_reader = list(filter(None, reader))

Comment: use `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.get_text()` so all the extra spaces and newlines ll be cutted. But in my opinion dictionary is the best way

Answer (score 1):

While opening a file use attribute (newline='')

```
with open(<filename>, mode='w', newline='') as file:
```

This will remove all new line characters while writing into a csv file.
Still Dictionary is better and well organized way.